# Empty ETW message in Windows Device Portal

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi2, windowsiot

I’m trying to log some stuff to ETW on my UWP application deployed to RPI2 (Windows IOT v.10.0.15063.0). On device portal I can see new logs but message is empty (payload gives me: “stringmessage:,”)

```
var _loggingChannel = new LoggingChannel("HA4IoT", null, new Guid("4bd2826e-54a1-4ba9-bf63-92b73ea1ac4a"));
_loggingChannel.LogMessage("Test", LoggingLevel.Information);
```

I’m trying to use LogEvent instead but any string field behaves like that - values logged are empty and saved CSV also have no data about logged stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry you hit this - there's a known regression in the ETW parsing logic in the Creator's Update for Device Portal that we're working to fix. Right now we don't have a workaround except to write a WPR profile and collect an ETL, and use the ETL to collect your logs.

You can track our fix here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18591439-loggingchannel-not-showing-string-message-content 
I'll update it when the code is fixed in an Insiders flight, and then once we know if the fix can be backported.

Update: This is fixed in the Fall Creators Update, and has been in flights for a couple months. Expect to see it in the next update of Windows across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

On my Raspberry Pi2 it works. I copied your code and executed it.

My Windows IoT Core 10 version is: *10.0.14393.67*

The result looks like this:

[image: Result]

I set the target version of the IoT background application to the following:

[image: Settings]

The CSV export also looks fine on my machine:

```
Timestamp,Provider,ID
04/27/2017-21:23:36.8150656,HA4IoT,0,Keyword:1,Level:4,ProviderName:HA4IoT,StringMessage:Test,TaskName:LogMsgInformation,WebbCompletePayload:stringmessage:test,
```

Best regards,
Christian